# How to save a file uploaded by a user with name+date+extention

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I succeeded saving a file as "namehmtddMMyyyy" but it removes the current extension.

```
        If (fileExt = ".csv") Or (fileExt = ".xml") Then
            Try
                FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\temp\name" & _
                   DateTime.Now.ToString("hmtddMMyyyy"))
```

How can I save the file in this format but still keep the current extension?

Comment: Why don you use FileExt:  FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\temp\name"+DateTime.Now.ToString("hmtddMMyyyy")+fileExt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
If (fileExt = ".csv") Or (fileExt = ".xml") Then
    FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\temp\name" & _
        DateTime.Now.ToString("hmtddMMyyyy") & fileExt)
```

Comment: Ofcourse! Thanks. But I added if (fileExt = ".csv") Then TRY

http://pastebin.com/kxDAQ9nD

Comment: I've already tried your first one, and it works. Its not such a big deal if the code is a bit longer. @p5Coder

Answer (score 2):

Not too familiar with VB.NET, but I know in C# I have to manually add the file extension when saving a file. Have you tried something like this? (Excuse any VB concat errors :) )

`FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\temp\name" & _
                   DateTime.Now.ToString("hmtddMMyyyy") + "." + fileExt)`

Comment: Replace '+' with '&' in VB.

Comment: Thanks now I know too

Comment: Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but don't you just need to concatenate the new name of the file with fileExt ?